# How to add instances on CKAN 2.0 package installation

Tags: ckan

I have setup CKAN 2.0.3 (package installation) on Ubuntu 12.04 which runs fine.
When I try to add a second instance using "ckan-create-instance", this runs into several errors. One reason is "common.sh" which gets invoked and is probably not up to date, because it relies on file locations (like /usr/share/pyshared/.../who.ini) or creates directories (like /var/lib/ckan/$instance/static) not appropriate for ckan 2.0.
As I cant see what else goes wrong:
Is there an easy way or a step-by-step-guide to create additional instances?
Even some kind of copying the default instance would fit.

Any advice is welcome and
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The CKAN package install only supports a single instance currently. I'm not sure what this `ckan-create-instance` command is, where did you find that?

If you want to deploy multiple instances of CKAN on one machine, we recommend doing a [source install](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/install-from-source.html).

We don't yet have instructions for how to boot a second CKAN instance, but basically you'd need to repeat most of the source install and deployment steps, but changing all the directories, user names, database names, etc:

- Create a second virtualenv (for example, `/usr/lib/ckan/my_second_site`) and install CKAN into it. Technically you can run two instances of CKAN off one virtualenv, but then they'd both have to run the same version of CKAN and extensions.
- Setup a second PostgreSQL database with a different user and database name, e.g. `ckan_my_second_site`
- Create a second CKAN config file in `/etc/ckan/my_second_instance/`.
- [Create a second Solr core](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/appendices/solr-multicore.html). As long as your CKAN instances are always going to run the same version of CKAN they can use the same Solr core and you can skip this step, but otherwise we recommend one Solr core per CKAN instance.
- Setup a second DataStore database, with a different name
- If using the FileStore, setup a second filestore directory
- Create a second WSGI script file at e.g. `/etc/ckan/my_second_instance/apache.wsgi`
- Create a second Apache config file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ckan_my_second_instance`
- Enable the second site with the `a2ensite` command

Comment: ckan-create-instance can be found at /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan_deb  Up to Version 1.8 it was documented too  
http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.8.2/install-from-package.html?highlight=ckan-create-instance  
As these script worked fine in 1.8, I'd really appreciate an update to work with 2.0.

Comment: That's a really old script that was used to package CKAN back in the CKAN 1.x days, it doesn't work anymore and is going to be deleted. See: https://github.com/okfn/ckan/pull/1401 The CKAN 2.0 package does not support multiple instances yet.